# Library 'uuid' from dart doesn't work with flutter?

Tags: flutter

I tried **flutter run** after adding the dependencies of the **Dart Library** [Uuid](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uuid).

**My changed dependencies**

```
  dependencies:
      uuid: 0.5.0 // or also - uuid: "^0.5.3"
```

**Errors from Flutter**

```
    Error: 'package:convert/src/hex/encoder.dart': malformed type: line 20 pos 13: cannot resolve class 'ChunkedConverter' from 'HexEncoder'
    extends ChunkedConverter<List<int>, String, List<int>, String> {
            ^
Failed to run the Flutter compiler. Exit code: 254

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\xxxx\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 329

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\xxxx\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 254
```

Why does this not work with flutter?

Comment: Please try `pub cache repair`

Comment: yeah thanks it worked

Answer (score 2):

After reading https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/29543#issuecomment-298888237 I think you might want to try adding a pubspec dependency on `convert: "^2.0.1"`. Does that help?